# Grant iOS permissions to Flutter Driver for integration test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, location-services, ios-permissions, flutterdriver

Using the Flutter `integration_test` package, I'm having trouble with a test that keeps failing due to an iOS permissions request that is inaccessible from the testing environment.

I tried `applesimutils` from [github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils](https://github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils) but when attempting to set the permissions before flutter drive, the application's bundle identifier isn't yet registered:

```
Got error:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
No such file or directory
```

Maybe this could be avoided by not creating a fresh Simulator instance every time, but I got past this by running `flutter drive ... & sleep 10` before the `applesimutils --setPermissions` command to allow the application to start first, but that still gives me:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════
The following LocationError object was thrown running a test:
  [LocationError code: 0, message: null]

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2   BackgroundGeolocation.getCurrentPosition.<anonymous closure>
  (package:flutter_background_geolocation/models/background_geolocation.dart:497:17)

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a bit more familiar with `xcrun simctl` I noticed that it can grant permissions before the application starts, as long as device has booted. `applesimutils` not required!

My working solution in the form of a shell script looks like this:

```
# Simulator setup
xcrun simctl create iOS14Simulator
xcrun simctl boot iOS14Simulator
xcrun simctl privacy iOS14Simulator grant location-always <YOUR_BUNDLE_ID>

# Launch integration test
flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test_driver.dart \
  --target=integration_test/app_test.dart

# Simulator teardown
xcrun simctl delete iOS14Simulator
```

Comment: this doesnt work, it still is asking to go to settings
I ran this command to grant all permissions `xcrun simctl privacy booted grant all <package bundle name>`

Comment: what is BUNDLE_ID? is it like package name like `com.id.myapp` on android?

Comment: @thekucays Yes, that's right.